# Magento 2 - Custom rest api endpoint for PDF download - net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

Tags: rest, magento2

- I have created **custom rest api endpoint in magento for downloading pdf file**.
- **When testing it locally:** From separate react JS project I am sending request to that endpoint and **file is downloaded successfuly**. http/1.1 protocol is used (checked in google chrome dev tools, network tab).
- After deployment to staging servers, when I try to make **request between staging servers from reactJS project to magento2 project**, then upon sending request it takes 30-40 seconds without getting any response and then error is shown in console. There is not anything in the error logs. http2 protocol is used (not sure if that can be a reason for issue).

> Failed to fetch - net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

Here is the piece of php code for downloading pdf file:

```
    ...
    $filename = $outputFileName . time() . '.' . $extension;
    $directoryTmpWrite = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::TMP);
    $directoryTmpWrite->writeFile($filename, $fileContent);

    return $this->fileFactory->create(
        $outputFileName . '.' . $extension,
        [
            'type' => 'filename',
            'value' => $filename,
            'rm' => true,
        ],
        DirectoryList::TMP, //basedir
        'application/octet-stream',
        ''
    );
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to resolve your error?  I'm having a similar issue

Comment: The problem was with php. I had to use output buffering to ensure that output from the script is stored to a buffer and then sent all together.

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved my issue?

I had to turn on output buffering in php in magento, to ensure that no output has been sent from a script and instead of that output has been store to a buffer and then sent all together from a script when script execution is finished.

So ob_start() fixed my issue. Right before return statement.